# SharePoint 2010 slow search

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I know this isn't a coding question but i wanted to throw it out there as the wealth of experience in the forum is high.

When we perform a search for the first time it's slow and it is fine after this.

Anyone got any ideas about why this is?

I think it's something to do with the cache being cleared out and was wondering if anyone could shed some light on how to get around this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

More than likely caused by the first "hit", the server is doing a lot of background processing. This would be the same as a webpage or database query.  The initial execution may be the slowest due to the volume of work it has to initially process, afterwards the data is cached.

Comment: I'm guessing this is on a per user basis?

Comment: @Truezplaya - It would entirely depend on if the search would return different results for each user. I'm sure under the hood certain information is cached and then incorporated into different search plans (for larger queries).

Comment: @Truezplaya - It would depend on the volume of data, for example, if you're doing like a full text search or loading a SP List with over 5,000 documents then it will be slow, however if you are doing it for like small 100 documents then it could be an actual performance issue that needs investigating.